# Low silhouette coefficient

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I am doing a kmeans clustering on a dataset of selling values of articles.

Each article has 52 selling values (one per week). I am trying to automatically calculate the optimum amount of clusters for any unkown dataset.

I tried two criteria: The elbow method and the silhouette coefficient.

For the silhouette coefficient I got for 1 to 20 clusters values from  0.059 to 0.117 which is (in my opinion) extremely low (heard about a normal of about 0.7).

For the elbow method I used the inertia_ (sum of squared distances) of the kmeans and appended it to a list for each iteration (also from 1 to 20). I got values between 21782 for k=1 and  15323 for k=20.

Now I am not really sure how to interpret these values. Is my data not that separable?

EDIT:
Thank you for the answer, as this seems to be a problem of data/preprocessing, here is how i process the data:

```
data = pd.read_csv('/home/dev/Desktop/TD_DM.csv', parse_dates=True, index_col=['DATE'], low_memory=False)
data[['QUANTITY']] = data[['QUANTITY']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
data_extracted = data.groupby(['DATE','ARTICLENO'])['QUANTITY'].sum().unstack()
print(data_extracted.index)
data_extracted = data_extracted.fillna(value=np.nan)
#data_extracted.index = pd.to_datetime(data_extracted.index.str[:-2], errors="coerce")
data_resampled = data_extracted.resample('W-MON', label='left', loffset=pd.DateOffset(days=1)).sum()
print(data_resampled)
```

Here is how the printed data_resampled looks like:

```
2017-12-19           13.0         2600.0            0.0            0.0   
2017-12-26           28.0         2840.0            0.0            0.0   
2018-01-02           34.0         4840.0            0.0            0.0   
2018-01-09           35.0         6140.0            0.0            0.0   
2018-01-16            6.0         5800.0            0.0            0.0   
2018-01-23            3.0         5980.0            0.0            0.0   
2018-01-30            0.0         6100.0            0.0            0.0   
2018-02-06           24.0         5020.0            0.0            0.0   
2018-02-13           60.0         6380.0            0.0            0.0   
2018-02-20           47.0         6220.0            0.0            0.0   
2018-02-27           73.0         5460.0            0.0            0.0   
2018-03-06           69.0         5780.0            0.0            0.0   
2018-03-13           33.0         5520.0            0.0            0.0   
2018-03-20           36.0         5540.0            0.0            0.0   
2018-03-27           27.0         5360.0            0.0            0.0   
2018-04-03           28.0         4920.0            0.0            0.0   
2018-04-10           31.0         5520.0            0.0            0.0   
2018-04-17           46.0         5660.0            1.0           21.0   
2018-04-24           26.0         5040.0           18.0           40.0   
2018-05-01           52.0         5540.0           18.0           40.0   
2018-05-08           36.0         5440.0            3.0           26.0   
2018-05-15           36.0         5720.0            5.0           18.0   
2018-05-22           52.0         4360.0            0.0           22.0   
2018-05-29           52.0         4760.0            0.0           18.0
```

The column headers would be the corresponding article number.

The next step is to locate one full year:

```
data_extracted = data_resampled.loc['2016-01-01' : '2016-12-31']
```

Then i start the preprocessing to remove columns with too many NaN's or 0's:

```
max_nan_count = 5
#there are headers at the 'bottom' too, so remove them
data_extrcated = data_extracted.iloc[:, :-1]
data_extracted = data_extracted.drop(data_extracted.columns[data_extracted.apply(lambda col: col.isnull().sum() > max_nan_count)], axis=1)
data_pct_change = data_extracted.astype(float).pct_change(axis=0).replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).fillna(0)
data_pct_change.drop([col for col, val in data_pct_change.sum().iteritems() if val == 0 ], axis=1, inplace=True)
print(data_pct_change)
```

And this is how the percentual change looks like:

```
2016-01-03       0.000000       0.000000       0.000000       0.000000   
2016-01-10       0.284091       0.062500       0.181548       0.252427   
2016-01-17       0.011799       0.117647       0.110831       0.211886   
2016-01-24       0.008746       0.807018       0.092971       0.140725   
2016-01-31      -0.020231      -0.411003       0.056017      -0.186916   
2016-02-07      -0.014749      -0.087912       0.033399      -0.098851   
2016-02-14       0.218563       0.138554       0.136882       0.229592   
2016-02-21      -0.233415      -0.343915      -0.322742      -0.296680   
2016-02-28       0.448718       0.661290       0.535802       0.439528   
2016-03-07      -0.057522      -0.048544      -0.107717       0.012295   
2016-03-14       0.009390      -0.030612       0.234234      -0.062753   
2016-03-21      -0.039535       0.000000      -0.068613       0.032397   
2016-03-28       0.232446       0.210526       0.153605       0.165272   
2016-04-04       0.001965       0.008696      -0.077446       0.028725   
2016-04-11      -0.133333      -0.185345      -0.148748      -0.219895   
2016-04-18       0.108597       0.174603       0.216263       0.199105   
2016-04-25       0.091837      -0.207207      -0.085349       0.016791   
2016-05-02      -0.052336       0.454545       0.149300      -0.023853   
2016-05-09       0.218935       0.000000       0.036536       0.058271   
2016-05-16       0.190939       0.210938      -0.080940       0.156306
```

Now i have an additional normalization step:

```
normalized_modeling_data = preprocessing.normalize(data_pct_change, norm='l2', axis=0)
normalized_data_headers = pd.DataFrame(normalized_modeling_data, columns=data_pct_change.columns)
normalized_modeling_data = normalized_modeling_data.transpose()
```

And this normalized_modeling_data is used for the kmeans clustering. The result of the k-means clustering looks very logical and reliable, so is there any mistake in my code?

Answer (score 1):

The Silhouette values definitely are very bad. Most likely, the data is not suitable for the clustering method you chose - or Silhouette is not appropriate. (But you probably used k-means, which is fine for Silbouette). Improve your preprocessing of the data!

Inertia values *cannot* be compared across data sets, because they are highly data dependant. If you scale your data by 10, you inertia values will be 100x larger. Since we don't have your data, we have absolutely no chance of interpreting these values: they could be huge, or tiny.

Comment: Blind "normalizing" barely does any good. You'd better do this in an informed way. Here, theoretical understanding may tell you to not normalize this at all.

Comment: Bad silhouette can also be cause by data that just does not have clusters. Are you sure there are clusters? Have you tried visualizing?

Comment: I visualized some of the article selling values and there were different shapes, so there must be clusters. my suggestion is that the silhouette coefficient converges towards the number of article numbers and gets maximum if every article number is in its own cluster. i normalized the data because giving the data_percentage_change to the kmeans.fit() gave me a weird result with worng scales on x and y axis. how can i pass this dataframe to kmeans so he treats each columns as 'data' from top to down?

Comment: If every article is its own cluster, the Silhouette by definition is 0.

Comment: well thats bad:/

Comment: I am a bit confused. What does each row in your dataset represents? The selling values of all articles for a specific date/week? If that is the case, then what you are trying to do is to cluster the various dates/weeks?

Answer (score 0):

Using the elbow method, you can also try to determine the number of clusters quantitatively in an automatic way (as opposed to doing it by eye using this method), if you introduce the quantity called the "elbow strength". Basically, it is based on the derivative of the elbow-plot with some more information-enhancing tricks. More details about the elbow strength can be found in the supplementary information of the following publication:

https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/2632-2153/abd87c